# pyqt and table widget clear contents

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am new to PYQT and I am trying to get a feel for it. I am trying to populate a table widget with 5 different push buttons. I need to clear out the table between each button push, but would like to leave the headers I have. I have tried a tablewidget clearcontents. but that clears everything and I am unsure of where to place it properly so it will clear the contents before each button push, that brings in the new info.

```
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):


    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(761, 637)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 550, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_output1_statement)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 580, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_output2_statement)

        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 610, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.get_output3_statement)

        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 580, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_output4_statement)

        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 580, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_output5_statement)

        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 741, 551))
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("name"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_1"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_2"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,3,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_3"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,4,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_4"))


        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "button1", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "button2", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "button3", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "button4", None))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "button5", None))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `clearContents()` method when you set the table headers in an appropriate way.

change:

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("name"))
self.tableWidget.setItem(0,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_1"))
self.tableWidget.setItem(0,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_2"))
self.tableWidget.setItem(0,3,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_3"))
self.tableWidget.setItem(0,4,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_4"))
```

to:

```
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("name"))
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_1"))
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_2"))
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_3"))
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_4"))
```

*EDIT Extra code after comments*

Maybe this helps you? I tried keeping as much of your code.

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        self.resize(761, 637)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 550, 201, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("released()"), self.get_output1_statement)

        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 741, 551))
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,     QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(5)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("name"))
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        for i in range(1, 5):
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i,     QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("column_{0}".format(i)))
        self.retranslateUi()

    def retranslateUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "button1", None))

    def get_output1_statement(self):
        self.tableWidget.clearContents()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("add some data"))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Ui_Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: That is awesome to keep the headers. Where would I insert the clear to get the table clear before each button push? When I try I can get it to just clear it once

Comment: What do you mean by "before" each button push? Do you want to clear the table when a button is pushed?

Comment: sorry yes, clear the table when button pushed, then also on the same"click" populate the table again with the current self.get_output2_statement for example

Comment: Ok, I posted some example anyway.. (posted before reading you comment). Success